# problem in $z$ transform

Tags: laplace-transform

Im having a hard time trying to solve this...

if $   (x_{k})_{k=0}^\infty $ is  a  causal succession such  as

$$ Z(x_{k}) = X(z)   \parallel z \parallel > R $$

prove that $$  Z( {{x_{k+2}}})  = Z^{2}X(z)-z^{2}x_{0}-zx_{1}, \parallel z \parallel > R$$

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

The problem essential states that
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{k} \ z^{-k} = X(z) 
\end{align}
and asks to find a similar result for $x_{k+2}$. It can be seen that
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{k+2} \ z^{-k} &= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} x_{k} \ z^{-k+2} \\
&= z^{2} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{k} \ z^{-k} - x_{0} z^{o} - x_{1} z^{-1} \right) \\ 
&= z^{2} X(z) - x_{0} z^{2} - x_{1} z.
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
Z(x_{k+2}) = z^{2} X(z) - x_{0} z^{2} - x_{1} z.
\end{align}

In a similar manor it can be shown that
\begin{align}
Z(x_{k+1}) = z X(z) - x_{0} z.
\end{align}